# How to start activity after some time in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing and android application in that I want to start another application(my second application). I am doing the following code

```
 Intent i= new Intent();
 i.setComponent(new ComponentName("my second app package","my class name"));
 startActivity(i);
```

It is working fine.

I want to hide the second application after 3 or 5 seconds for that I am following the below code

```
 Timer t=new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent("first app package","first app class name" );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                }
            }, 5000);
```

But this code is not working as I expected only for my second application. But other applications are working fine. Instead thread I also tried Handler, alaram manager also no sucess.  Please any one help me in this.

Is I want to do any code change in my second application or what is the problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: try `handler.postDelayed()`

Comment: Tried that also no success @ M D

Comment: `Intent i = ("first app package","first app class name" );` this obviously doesn't compile...

Comment: It's not possible. You can only kill it's process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use thread but main thing is you have to call finish() method to finish current activity.

```
     Thread thread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                   Thread.sleep(3000);

                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(1stActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

in the try block i put Thread.sleep(3000) you can change it do your work in try block

Comment: Dont use Thread.sleep as it cause main thread to sleep. so Its better to use Handler().postDelayed

Comment: @AjayShrestha That's not quite right: this is creating a _new_ thread and blocking _that_ thread instead.  `Handler.postDelayed` is better, but only because it's not creating a pointless extra thread.

Comment: `catch (Exception e)` is generally a bad idea that will mask errors.  If you're expecting a specific exception, catch _that_ exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                public void run() {
                        // your code to start second activity. Will wait for 3 seconds before calling this method

startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivityClass.this,SecondActivityClass.class));
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Use above code after onCreate of first activity

Comment: Tried this also no sucess :(

Comment: @Krishna: `Tried this also no sucess` : what problem getting using this answer?

Comment: Second application activity only in the front. The first application is not coming to foreground

Answer (score 1):

Try postDelayed or Timer method

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //Do something after 100ms
     //Intent i = new Intent("first app package","first app class name" );
      Intent i = new Intent (this , SecondActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
      }
    }, 100);


// Time method 

import java.util.Timer;

...
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Your database code here
  }
}, 2*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    startActivity(secondActivityIntent);
}catch(Exception e){
   //print error here
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? Blocking UI thread is the worst thing that you can do.

Comment: Also, `catch (Exception e)` is generally a bad idea that will mask errors.  If you're expecting a specific exception, catch _that_ exception.

Answer (score 0):

You want the second application to hide after few seconds, Please put this code inside `onCreate()` of your second application's main `Activity`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
            YourActivity.this.finish();
     }
 }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Your Code here
                }

            });
```

Put this code inside run method of your timer task.And it will work.Hope it will help.Thanks.